# Looking for a benchmark utilizing bit-wise rotate

Tags: rotation, benchmarking, bit-manipulation

I am looking for a common/cannonical (or not so common :P) algorithm or benchmark which heavily uses a bitwise rotate on a 16 bit, 32 bit, or 64 bit integer data type.  The bitwise rotate can be implemented in any way, such as a call to a compiler intrinsic, call to a user-level function, inline bitwise operations, etc...  Does anyone have an example of such an algorithm or benchmark?

Answer (score 1):

The MD5 hash algorithm from RFC 1321 is fairly rotate intensive (32-bit rotations). Similarly, the SHA1 hash algorithm from RFC 3174 also uses a fair amount of rotates.

RFC 1321: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1321.txt
RFC 3174: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3174.txt